# how to set Sec-WebSocket-Key in web socket header?

Tags: html, websocket

How to set **

> Sec-WebSocket-Key
>   ** in web socket header?
>    Can we set that key or not? And if so then how?

Comment: how to set Sec-WebSocket-Key from websocket header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is something that the WebSocket client sets itself. It is part of the WebScket handshake, you don't need to use that header. In fact, there is no way of setting HTTP headers on WebSocket connections.